# Camera moves on mouse orbit

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
function LateUpdate () {   
if (isCameraInputIgnored() ) {
        return;
}   

if (target && Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
    x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xSpeed * 0.02;
    y -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySpeed * 0.02;

    y = ClampAngle(y, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);

    var rotation = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, 0);

    var position = rotation * Vector3(0.0, 10.0, -distance) + target.position;

    transform.rotation = rotation;
    transform.position = position;
}
}
```

This is the function that rotates my object. When i hit play and click on mouse (doesn't matter where I'm on the screen) my camera is changing it's position by setting . Any ideas on how to stop that ?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GfjY.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxMQP.jpg]

I've added 2 pictures for details. i hope to understand what is my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by changing the camera position in the inspector.